# get value for a cookie from a bootrap modal with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

I'm trying to create a modal that has 2 options: yes or no. When a user selects no I will create a condition if `value=no` then do not display modal.

The issue is that I cannot accomplish it. If is answer is yes I can manipulate the info, I need to display a modal asking a question, get the users answer and based on this and do something every 15 days.

my code is currently not working properly

```
<script>
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    function checkCookie() {

        $('#hewant').on('click', function() {
            var valyes = $(this).text();
            console.log(valyes);
        });

        $('#hedont').on('click', function() {
            var valno = $(this).text();
            console.log(valno);
        });
        var user = getCookie("username");

        if (user != "") {
            alert("Welcome again " + user);
        } else {
            $("#myModalcashout").modal();
            user = "testing me";
            if (user != "" && user != null) {
                setCookie("username", user, 15);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<body onload="checkCookie()">

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModalcashout">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- for modal to active manually->
         <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-body">

                    <p style="text-align:center">test</p>
                    <p style="text-align:center">question</p>
                    <p style="text-align:center">for u</p>
                    <div id="hewant" value="yes"> yes i am </div>
                    <div id="hedont" value="no"> no i dont</div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: "my code is currently not working properly" you need to be more specific. What exactly is not working?

Comment: 2 issues, 1 i cannot get to modal answer to be become the cookie value, 2 the script which is getting the value of the div, only works within the onlick function, i need variable to be the cookie value,.. meaning if the user click on yes i am then that become the cookie value or if he click no i dont also become the cookie value

Comment: why don't you call the setCookie function from within the onclick?

Comment: cause i dont know how to, im just learning about cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restructured your code for you. For starters you only need 1 listener for both buttons, which can be assigned using `class` on the buttons in the modal (which I changed from `div` to `button` tags.

**Note**: "Run this code snippet" will not work in this sand boxed environment in regards to cookie manipulation so you will have to test this yourself.

There is now a showModal() function that you will call on load that is responsible for showing your modal and attaching a click listener to both buttons on the modal.

When the user clicks yes or no on the modal we get their answer and pass it to `checkCookie()` function which does as you ask.

I replaced your create and set cookie functions with ones that are tested and work (also added eraseCookie()) there is a great explanation about all 3 functions [Here](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

```js
showModal();

function showModal() {
  // only show modal if cookie for the user is null
  var user = readCookie("username");
  if (user != null) {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
  } 
  else {
    user = "testing me";
    $("#myModalcashout").modal();

    // add listener on buttons
    $('.modalButton').on('click', function() {
      $('#myModalcashout').modal().hide();
      var answer = $(this).val();
      console.log(answer);
      
      // create a cookie with the users answer to the modal
      createCookie("username", answer, 15);
    });
  }
}

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  } else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModalcashout">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- for modal to active manually->
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p style="text-align:center">test</p>
        <p style="text-align:center">question</p>
        <p style="text-align:center">for u</p>
        <button class="modalButton" value="yes"> yes i am </button>
        <button class="modalButton" value="no"> no i dont</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i highly appreciate your answer, i tested it, but is not working the way i need it or maybe i dont know how to use it. all i need is this, when modal pop it as the question, now yes or no, should be store as a cookie for 15 days, so explample if i choose no, when i refrfesh the page modal should not display, i set a console.log but anytime page refresh i get back the same modal or even after i select option the modal keep poping up and the answer(yes or no is erase) i need this answer to remain

Comment: now the window that pop up it soometing i dont need anymore, when i select and aswer (yes or no) the window pop up with a testing me message, i need is to store the yes answer , kinda how the resting me message is store but instead on a pop i need to hold it and turn it into a variable to tell modal what to do with this variable, if answer is redirect for exapample if answer is no, do not redirect, since modal sould only pop up once every 15 days

Comment: okay I updated my example to only show the modal if there is no cookie already for "username" cookie. If you don't understand the code try to ask questions about specific parts you don't understand

Comment: // if the user says yes to the modal then create a cookie.
      if(valyes === "yes"){
         createCookie("username", user, 15);
      }      i will always need the answer even if is no,, i need actually the coockie value to be the answer either is yes or no, mean when ever i refresh the page the cookie value is yes/no, once i have this then when page loads again the cookie value must be a variable, so if valyes ==yes create cookie such or if valyes == create cookie such, cause i need to manipulte it,

Comment: with the code i got this error: too much recursion  readCookie showModal

Comment: Okay I edited it one last time. You should be able to make these changes yourself.

Comment: while you was editing i was doing changes on it and with what you just gave me is almost what i got,, i really thank you for your time and patience i would´´ve never done it without your help